# OSClass search by id item result specific product with this ID

Tags: php, mysql, osclass

I am new in OSClass. When I am searching something using search bar like "apartman", there will be result item, which contain a "apartman". It is ok. But a would like to add function to search. If I create new ads, like "car toyota", there will create a unique ID item and page looks like this "mydomain.com/index.php?page=item&id=2". The ID of this item is id 2. And I want, if I do a search with this value "2", result "car toyota", becuse this item ID is 2.

Does anyone know, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

By default it's not possible to use the search to search by ID's, but you could create a plugin

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using "osc_query_item()", for example below mention code will return you details of an item that have an id=12345.

```
osc_query_item("id=12345");
if( osc_count_custom_items() == 0) { ?>
    <p class="empty"><?php _e('No Listings', 'modern') ; ?></p>
<?php 
} 
else { ?>
    <?php 
    while ( osc_has_custom_items() ) { 
        ?> 
        <div style="width:100%; float:left;">
            <div style="width:20%; float:left;">
            <?php
                if( osc_images_enabled_at_items() ) { 
                    if( osc_count_item_resources() ) { 
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo osc_item_url(); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo osc_resource_thumbnail_url(); ?>" width="75" height="56" title="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" alt="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" />
                        </a>

                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo osc_current_web_theme_url(); ?>/images/no_photo.gif" width="75" height="56" alt="" title=""/><?php
                    } 
                }
            ?>
            </div>
            <div style="width:80%; float:left;">
                <strong><a href="<?php echo osc_item_url(); ?>"><?php echo osc_item_title(); ?></a></strong><br>
                <strong><?php echo osc_item_formated_price(); ?> - <?php echo osc_item_city(); ?> ( <?php echo osc_item_region(); ?>) - <?php echo osc_format_date(osc_item_pub_date()); ?> </strong>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
    } ?><?php  
}
```